# how to turn on word wrap in linux less viewer?

Tags: linux, less-unix

Word wrap mode of "less" viewer is disabled by default in the system I work on. According to "less" viewer help, it is disabled with -S or --chop-long-lines flags. I did not find how to force word wrap on my system. Is there any known flag, or any other way, for enabling the mode?

Comment: What do you mean by `force word wrap on my system`?

Comment: my system = virtual linux machine in my work (logging in from windows with VNC viewer), cent os 6.5, gnome, tc shell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may try using the `LESS` environment variable. For example, you can put the following into system-wide shell initialization script (`/etc/profile` for bash/ksh):

```
 export LESS="-S "
```

Comment: thanks. solved. when i do echo "$LESS" i see "-i-S-q-u-R". That's why word wrap is disabled by default.

Answer (score 27):

Word wrapping is disabled using `-S`. Following the man page, you can reset that option by passing `-+S` to the command line.

Let's say you have `$LESS` set to `-S`, you can re-enable it on the command line with

```
less -+S file
```

Comment: Great tip for a plus sign!